# Any sumfunc in Perl by default

Tags: perl, optimization

Code

```
sub sumfunc {
    my (@x) = @_; my $sum = 0;
    for(my $i=0; $i<=$#x; $i++) {
        $sum += $x[$i];
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

Use

```
my $Sx  = sumfunc(@x);
```

**How can you do sumfunc better?** 
Any default function for this event in Perl 5.18.2?
To sum up everything in @x. 
I feel a separate function extraneous.

Comment: List::Util contains sum function that do what you want

Comment: @cuonglm Name of such function? It is not `sum` or `sum0` here http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html

Comment: You can use both. `sum0` will return 0 instead of undef when given an empty list. http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#%24num_or_undef-%3d-sum-%40list

Comment: `sub sum { my $sum; $sum += $_ for @_; $sum; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick search shows that a function to sum a list is `sum` and is available from the standard module [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html).

The documentation's [synopsis](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#SYNOPSIS) shows that it's necessary to declare the functions that will be required. For example,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw(sum);

my @a = qw(1 3 5 7 9);
my $b = sum @a;
print "b=$b.\n";
```

The same documentation tree allows searching that is specific to your Perl 5.18.2; the function is (still) available there.

Answer (score 1):

I always try to keep the list of modules and other external dependencies as low as possible. This will also work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @a = qw(1 3 5 7 9);
my $b = 0;
map {$b += $_} @a;
print "b=$b.\n";
```

`map` executes the block for each element of the list, setting `$_` in turn to each element.

You could also use `grep`, the difference is that `map` returns a list of each result of the expression (i.e. (1, 4, 9, 16, 25) in this case), and `grep` returns a list of those elements for which the expression evaluates to true which in this case is (1, 3, 5, 7, 9); if there was a zero as first element in the input list it would not be returned, or if the second element was -1 it would also result in an 0-valued expression and hence not be returned. However in this case the difference is not relevant.

Comment: This would be nice if it would be more readable and extensible to square sums and cross-sums etc.